# Which country/empire was the dominant hegemon for the longest time?

Tags: military, economy

Say the USA has been the worlds most dominant power for 75 years.  Before that one could argue the British Empire during the Victorian era, approx 1810 to 1915, was the world dominant power.  Other dominent hegemons I can think of are the Spanish empire from 1500 to 1700, the Roman Empire, the Persian Empire.  What country/empire has been a world hegemon for the longest solid period of time?

I know deciding world power is much more difficult in ancient times.  Hegemon one who economically \ militarily \ politically dominates all they encounter in their region.

Comment: I would say that the Brits went from 1810 to 1945, not 1915.

Comment: This question makes no sense. No power was ever a "world dominant" or "world hegemon". The Roman and  Persian empires just did not know about much of the rest of the world. Same applies to the Arab Chalifate and various empires in China. British empire was large and powerful but it never "dominated the world".

Comment: The question makes perfect sense @Alex. "Which power retained global primacy for the longest time?" It's entirely valid.

Comment: Then it has to be reworded. You already replaced "dominance" to "primacy", now I recommend to replace "global" to "regional" so that China and the Chalifate qualify.

Comment: There has never been a worldwide hegemonal power, from prehistory through until present.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I removed world from the title, it could have been misleading.  I am really just interested in the longest one power has been on top so to say.

Comment: `approx 1810 to 1915` `the Brits went from 1810` What's so special in 1810? Why not 1815?

Comment: 1810 was just an approximation,  1815 (and the removal of Napolean) would probably be a better start date.  Though I would still put it from 1815 to WWI, rather than 1945, but I am sure that is semantics and probably best suited to a whole other topic!

Comment: The Roman Republic and Empire was the most powerful state in the Mediterranean area from about  200 BC to about 425 AD or 625 years and from about 535 AD to about 650 AD, and it was the most powerful European state on and off for more centuries, alternating with Bulgaria, the Carolingian Empire, the Holy Roman Empire, the Kingdom of Sicily, the Mongols, etc. up to about 1282.

Comment: The Arab Empire? It was in non-stop expansion from the time of Islam's origin (the religious leader also being the military leader) all the way up till the Industrial Revolution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well for starters, the United States has not been the world's "most dominant" power for 75 years. It was in competition with the USSR after the Second World War. There's an argument that the U.S might have been the stronger of the two powers, but it certainly did not "dominate" - which was pretty the basis for Cold War competition between the two powers.

What was naively referred to as "the end of history" or a period of global U.S primacy really only stretched from 1991 to 2007. (The dissolution of the Soviet Union to the Lehman's brother collapse).

This depends on how far we are willing to stretch the definitions. We could say Rome was the longest surviving "world" power. But in reality the Roman Empire went through a few incarnations, and by today's standards was really only a *regional hegemon*. It never truly possessed what could be described as a 'world power' status. I mean, the Romans never even kept a foothold above the Rhine. There were other Empires in existence that the Romans didn't really have much awareness of such as China, whom it could never hope to dominate.

The only real candidate here is the British Empire during the period mentioned. But then, we run into semantic difficulties with the term "dominate". The British Empire was powerful militarily, but it used its economic power rather than its military to protect its vital interests. The British still had a number of near peer competitors militarily, and it was not able to unilaterally impose its will on other nations through the use of either lever (see the Crimean War).

So I would say the British Empire, but it's murky.

Comment: Why the Lehman Brothers collapse - an event that few people other than economists (and not all of them) either know or care about - as marking the end of "the end of history"?  I think a better date would be 9/11, as marking the resurgence of Islamic jihad.

Comment: I would say that whilst "a few" is an understatement; nearly everybody on the planet is familiar with the consequences of that event. 
At 9/11 the U.S still possessed all of its husbanded military and economic might. By 2007 the military and diplomatic might had been squandered in an Iraqi quagmire and the economic strength in the subprime housing crisis.

Comment: You could also argue the mess in Iraq and failure in Afghanistan showed the limits of American power. I tend to point to this, rather than Lehman or 9/11 directly as the end of American hegemon.

Comment: Sure, but it took time for those particular messes to evolve - and if we examine the timelines - 2007 is the year which truly demonstrated it - the American surge in Iraq (which was supposed to pacify the country but really marked a handover - an echo  of "Vietnamisation") and the resurgence of the Taliban in Southern Afghanistan. Lehman Bros wasn't the only reason I chose 2007 ;)

Comment: @Anaryl: Strange, as I'm not familiar with consequences of Lehman Brothers collapse, though I consider myself fairly well-read.  Just the opposite, in fact: it was just one of many consequences of a normal (though severe) downturn in the economic cycle.  I also disagree with your military analysis, though there's no room to discuss it.  Basically, 9/11 marked the point at which it became obvious (at least to some :-)) that jihad had become a world problem on the lines of communism, thereby marking the resumption of history.

Comment: You've never heard of the Global Financial Crisis?

Comment: As for 9/11 whether it marked the increase of global awareness of jihadism is not the issue. It's whether the period of U.S primacy ended at 9/11. There's no dispute that did not happen at 9/11. The "arrival" of global jihadism did not mean the end of the unipolar global order. Therefore equating 9/11 with the end of U.S primacy is a non-sequitur.

Comment: @Anaryl: Choosing any past event to mark the end of US primacy is a non-starter, because it hasn't happened yet :-)  While of course I've heard of the so-called global financial crisis, it was not a consequence of the collapse of Lehman Brothers (quite the reverse), nor (again) was it anything more than a large swing in the economic cycle.

Comment: I thought you said you were well read?